# allow only lowercase user registrations

Tags: user-registration, validation, username

I'm trying to get allow only lowercase usernames are valid usernames in my wordpress blog.
I managed to write a function but it does not seem to work.

```
add_filter('validate_username' , 'simple_user', 1, 2);
    function simple_user($valid, $username ) {
            if (preg_match("/[a-z0-9]+/", $username)) {
                // there are spaces
                return $valid=false;
            }
        return $valid;
    }
```

Any ideas with getting this to work ? i tried this but it never worked.
I will be very appreciative if someone could help me with this one.
Thank you

Comment: why not just use strtolower($username); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter `validate_username` sends and expects a *boolean* value, not a string.

Hook into `sanitize_user` and use `mb_strtolower()`.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_user', 'wpse_83689_lower_case_user_name' );

function wpse_83689_lower_case_user_name( $name )
{
    // might be turned off
    if ( function_exists( 'mb_strtolower' ) )
        return mb_strtolower( $name );

    return strtolower( $name );
}
```

Comment: +1 for using [mb_strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) if available and falling back on [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) if not.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this on wordpress' [codex site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/sanitize_user) for the sanitize_user filter.

`add_filter('sanitize_user', 'strtolower')`

According to the site this will force usernames to be lowercase.